# cannot add sqlite dependancy to pom

Tags: sqlite, intellij-idea

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvDB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

i'm using the latest version of intelliJ

it lists all 3 lines relating to the dependancy as having problems.

```
Dependency 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0' not found
Dependency 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0' not found
Dependency 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0' not found
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of JetBrains tool.
Make sure you click on the Load Maven Changes button (Ctrl+Shift+O) after changing pom.xml
[image of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DyhP.png)